# how to avoid gRPC async server streaming missing messages on start?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I've implemented an async server stream of messages and I have tests that call the rpc, then cause a message to be sent from the server, and then wait for the `onNext()`.

Sometimes the tests fail because the rpc call arrives to the server after I cause a message. If I add a sleep of 300 millisecond on the server side, it fails consistently.

I've tried adding `withWaitForReady()` and it didn't help.

Is there a standard way to block an async stub until the method on the server side is finished?

Comment: It's not clear to me what's being asked. Part of this is I don't know whether it is client or server waiting for `onNext()` and what "cause a message" is talking about. "Blocking" an async stub is also confusing. Try rewording?